# Linux add new line after regex match very large file with no line breaks

Tags: regex, linux

I have a file which is large `~5.1GB` in size and unfortunately it does not have any line breaks.

Fortunately, It is easy to find where I want a line break to be inserted which is after the following regex:

`\{(.*?)\}`

which matches everything inside `{` and `}`.

I tried using grep to find the outputs that matched the above but I got the following error:

`grep: memory exhausted`

because it was trying to load the full 5GB line into memory. Is there a way to process this without loading it into memory and appending a new line after every regex match?

Im not very experienced in Linux, for reference this will be ran on Amazon Linux EC2 instance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `sed`'s inline replace:

```
sed -i 's/{[^}]*}/&\n/g' file
```

---

`-i` option specifies that the files should edited in place.

The script `'s/{[^}]*}/&\n/g'` states that `s`ubstitute occurrences of `{[^}]*}` with `&\n` (where `&` means the matched string itself) `g`lobally on the `file`.

Comment: Thank you, could you explain what that actually does? the sed syntax confuses me in all honesty. In addition, the file is now `1.1GB` rather than the original 5.5, is this a normal side effect?

Comment: @ChrisEdwards Updated reply.

Comment: Also, doesn't seem to have completed the file writing. All the original data does not seem to be there.

Comment: `-i` means edit files in place,  `s/patternToReplace/replaceString/g` let `sed` substitude the mathed pattern.